# What files I should use in Automation testing framework

Tags: selenium, frameworks, automation

I am making Automation Framework using Selenium , JAVA, Maven, TestNG & Eclipse.
So my question is regarding **which TYPE OF FILE I should use for:**

1. Keeping test Data ? (Right now I am using XML file as it is light &
   free unlike Excel)
2. Creating test case. ? (Currently I am using simple .Java text file for each test case)
3. For creating Reports ? (Thinking to make XML report & then display it using HTML file)

**Will be nice if you share Pros & Cons along with your views/recommendation/suggestion.**

I think this will help me finalize my file structure. We can add functionality & facilities anytime.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Less response has inferrred me that there are less people in Testing arena. When I used to do development in PHP & JAVA, there were crowdy :0

Answer (score 0):

1. Keeping test Data, you might want to try using .Java files to store data, then use getter and setter. If you are using TestNG you can use the annotation @DataProvider() which will really help you on keeping test data.

Constants can also be put in . Java files as an interface

2. Creating test case --> It is a good thing to use .Java file
3. Creating reports --> Yep, you got the idea. Try to use TestNG, it's easy to set up.

Comment: Thanks Raymond. I will be looking into @DataProvider()

Comment: Thanks @Raymond. I will be looking into @DataProvider(). For reports, I am not finding TestNG reports much appropriate, because whenever error occurs whether minor or major, it just ends the test. If we handle that error using error handling, then TestNG report shows it as a Pass. That is why to log it as an error I am making my own reports. For more independence we will have to use own reports.

Comment: @TejasSaini hmm, I am not sure TestNG will immediately end the whole test. It will only end the current test priority, not the whole test.

Comment: Right, when error occurs it ends the current test case not the whole test Suite. Let me get explain my view with the following example. **Suppose** we want to test 6 links on a page & there is problem with the 4th and 5th link. We now run the test, the first 3 steps pass as the 3 links are fine. It fails on 4th step while verifying the 4th link. Now if we check reports, we do not get to know that there was problem with 5th link too. I do not want to end my test case while verifying a trivial thing.

Comment: @TejasSaini I see your point, that being said, you can always save your verification in a boolean value. In the last step of the test priority, do a verification based on a boolean value of the previous verification.

Example: Link 3 is broken: assign boolean value of A to be false

Link 4 is broken, add assign value of B to be false

In the end of the step, use a simple if (below is the simplest form of the logic)

if(A is false)
fail the test because Link 3 is broken

Of course you can make your own modification

Comment: I guess I will have to code this everywhere. Therefore, I'll be looking to solve it with a more general code. Thanks a lot buddy.Do  you also face less no of replies on Testing related questions.

Comment: @TejasSaini I dont think it'll be a problem. If you will do this kind of verification oftenly, just create a helper class that contains the universal method. Simply extend the helper class in order to use the verification method.

Yeah, we just hv to be patient :)